# Python - Plotting two 3D graphs with a contour map

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, 3d

I am trying to plot a figure in Python with two 3D graphs (same function, different angles) and a 2D contour map of the same function and I'm not sure why but the two first figures are okay and the contour map is weird, it appears at the bottom of the two first figures and the sizing is all weird (see the picture attached). Is there a way to place the map at the right of the 2 other figures and to resize it to make it more like a square?

Thank you for your help.

Here's my code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.01)
y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.01)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z = 5 + (10 * X**2 + 20 * Y**2) * np.exp((-X**2)-(Y**2)) + 3 *np.sin(X) - np.sin(Y)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))

ax1 = plt.subplot(131, projection='3d')
surf1 = ax1.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm)

ax2 = plt.subplot(132, projection='3d')
surf2 = ax2.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
for angle in range(0,360):
    ax2.view_init(20, angle)
    plt.pause(.001)

ax3 = plt.subplot(133)
surf3 = ax3.contour(X, Y, Z, colors='black', linestyles='dashed')
plt.clabel(surf3, fmt = '%.0f', inline=True, fontsize=8)


ax1.set_xlabel('X')
ax2.set_xlabel('X')
ax3.set_xlabel('X')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y')
ax2.set_ylabel('Y')
ax3.set_ylabel('Y')
ax1.set_zlabel('Z')
ax2.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```

[image: Here's the screenshot of the figures]

Comment: Doesn't ```plt.subplots()``` have an ncols and nrows argument?
When I do multiplots I always do this:
```fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3,nrows=1)```
That way I get three plots next to each other in the same fig instance. EDIT: It appears you are opening a second figure instance and that's why that happens. Tie all three ax instances to the fig instance explicitly and don't call any plt.somethingsomething functions separately. If you make a plt. call and it isn't attributed to an ax, it will create a new fig sometimes.

Comment: Btw I'm 100 % stealing this template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.01)
y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.01)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z = 5 + (10 * X**2 + 20 * Y**2) * np.exp((-X**2)-(Y**2)) + 3 *np.sin(X) - np.sin(Y)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 1, projection='3d')
surf1 = ax1.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm)

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 2)
surf3 = ax3.contour(X, Y, Z, colors='black', linestyles='dashed')
plt.clabel(surf3, fmt = '%.0f', inline=True, fontsize=8)


ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 3, projection='3d')
surf2 = ax2.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm)


for angle in range(0,360):
    ax2.view_init(20, angle)
    plt.pause(.001)

ax1.set_xlabel('X')
ax2.set_xlabel('X')
ax3.set_xlabel('X')
ax1.set_ylabel('Y')
ax2.set_ylabel('Y')
ax3.set_ylabel('Y')
ax1.set_zlabel('Z')
ax2.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```

Comment: I think the problem is related to multithreading (or lack thereof) in matplotlib. Maybe you can apply it, if you know how, but I don't know. I simply changed the order of subplot definitions. You are basically recalling the animated one again and again. Until that hasn't run out (Which will only happen, if you close the window), the last plot (contour map) will never be plotted. Because you are running everything in the same thread, all calls will be executed chronologically. And since the second call blocks everything, the third subplot gets moved to a separate figure, I guess.